# JSON in Python with Ajax

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, json, django

I have had this problem for couple of days now, My response from the Django is

```
di = { 0 : 'bat' , 1 : 'ball' } 
js = json.dumps(js , indent=4)

print js

"""
{
     "0": "bat", 
     "1": "ball"
}
"""
return HttpResponse(js)
```

now in my Ajax function:

```
$.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "/some/url",
        data: {
            'name': "myname",
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
        },
        dataType: "json",

        success: function (data) {

            alert(data)

            var to_parse = $.parseJSON(data);

            alert(to_parse)


        }
    });
    return false
}
```

I expect in `alert(data)` the json value, but instead it get this: `[object object]`

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried "alert(data[0])", JSON is kind of like an array, you have to get the index of you object to display the data

Comment: *Where am I going wrong?*: You are using `alert()` as a debugging tool. Your AJAX call *worked* and produced a JavaScript object. `alert()` however won't print the *contents* of that object.

Comment: console.log(data) will display the data you want, in Google Chrome you can press F12 to go to the debugger and then view the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are telling Jquery that your data is json via the "dataType: "json"" option, jquery goes ahead and turns your text into a javascript object.  So when you do alert(data) you get the object not the text.  You should either remove the line where you parese the data to json yourself or remove dataType:json from your jquery options.

Just to answer you question explicitly, replace alert(data) with alert(JSON.stringify(data))

Answer (score 1):

Use console.log(data);

This will display the contents to the console, you can view the console in Google Chrome by pressing F12 and clicking "Console"

[image]